# How to access the CC field using the keyboard in Microsoft Outlook for Mac

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts

In the email sending pane, when focused on the To field and pressing tab, the focus jumps to the Subject field skipping the Cc and Bcc fields. How can I reach the Cc field using only the keyboard.

I am using Microsoft Outlook for Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Omtara, you can make the CC (and/or BCC) field visible by default in the Composing settings for New Outlook for Mac. Then you can do easy tabbing.

[image: Composing Settings screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot your provide, I noticed that you are using the New Outlook for Mac. As I know, there seems to be no such way to use the keyboard to directly hit CC and BCC fields in New Outlook for Mac.

Considering that you want to use only the tab key to switch one by one when filling in the contents of the email, as a workaround, it's suggested that you could click CC and BCC as soon as you create a new message, so that these two fields will be displayed in the next two lines of to field as shown in the following figure. And you can use the tab key to start filling out each section of this message, which is very convenient.

[image]

***Updated:***

I continued to do a lot of research and testing in new outlook for Mac, and still got nothing. But I found that i can use the tab key to jump to CC and BCC field after turning off New Outlook and enabling BCC under Options tab, as shown in the figure below.
[image]

If you really need to implement this function in New Outlook, it is recommended that you could [submit feedback](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11#platform=macOS) in the Outlook client. Hope Microsoft will pay attention to this issue in the future.

Comment: Not convenient. I need a solution that only uses keyboard.

Comment: Hi Omtara, since pictures and links can't be added in the comment area, I have updated in my last reply. Please check it out. Hope to help you~

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.